# How to join endpoint with IP adress from environmental variables, in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, opc-ua

I'm trying to get the Kubernetes service IP using env variable to an endpoint inside a python app.

For example in NodeJs:

```
(`http://${process.env.AUTH_ADDRESS}/hashed-password/` + password);
```

using backticks and `${}` IP address is fetched from the env variable

In Python I tried

```
opc.tcp://"+str(os.environ.get('USER_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST'))+":4840/
```

but the result is actually something like ('10.98.191.127', 4840). I need it in a format like '10.98.191.127:4840' I have tried concatenate strings individually

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the port `4840` to `str` type. Something like:

```
str(os.environ.get('USER_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST'))+":"+str(4840)
```

Something I would do is to use f-string format, something like:

```
f"{os.environ.get('USER_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST')}:4840"
```